# How can I return a select-query that canges based on the parameters i use when calling a function?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have been wrestling with this problem for a while now. I want to make a function that takes parameters. The function is supposed to, with user submitted parameters, change a select-statment and after return/run the select.

**The function:**

```
create or replace FUNCTION F_GET_TABLE(column1_in varchar2, column2_in varchar2)
    return query
is 
    base_query constant varchar2(5000 char) :=
    'select column1, column2 from CustomersTable;';
begin    
    replace(replace(base_query, 'column1', column2_in),'column2', column2_in );
    queryToReturn query := base_query;
    return queryToReturn;
end F_GET_TABLE;
```

**In my head the end result should be that I call the function like this:**

```
select F_GET_TABLE('f_name','e_mail') from dual;
```

**And I should have the same result as if I wrote the select-statment as:**

```
select f_name, e_mail from CustomersTable;
```

So I've tried in different ways to make the function return the query as I've described. However the best I managed to do was return a varchar2 with the select-statement - however then I have to remove "" from the start and end of the select-block and run it manually.. I couldn't seem to find any answers to my problem while searching the internet, please help me out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_table (column1_in  VARCHAR2,
  2                                          column2_in  VARCHAR2)
  3     RETURN VARCHAR2
  4  IS
  5     base_query  VARCHAR2 (5000) := 'select column1, column2 from emp';
  6  BEGIN
  7     RETURN REPLACE (REPLACE (base_query, 'column1', column1_in),
  8                                          'column2', column2_in);
  9  END f_get_table;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_get_table('ename', 'job') from dual;

F_GET_TABLE('ENAME','JOB')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select ename, job from emp

SQL>
```

---

If you want to return *result*, then return ref cursor:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_table (column1_in  VARCHAR2,
  2                                          column2_in  VARCHAR2)
  3     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  4  IS
  5     base_query  VARCHAR2 (5000) := 'select column1, column2 from emp';
  6     l_rc        SYS_REFCURSOR;
  7  BEGIN
  8     OPEN l_rc FOR
  9        REPLACE (REPLACE (base_query, 'column1', column1_in),
 10                 'column2',
 11                 column2_in);
 12
 13     RETURN l_rc;
 14  END f_get_table;
 15  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT f_get_table ('ename', 'job') FROM DUAL;

F_GET_TABLE('ENAME',
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
KING       PRESIDENT
BLAKE      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER
JONES      MANAGE
<snip>
```

Comment: Yes that is my alternativ solution! But I would like the return to be the actual result of the select - not the actual select-statment. But thanks for the input!

Comment: Aha; didn't understand that. One option is to return a refcursor - see edited answer.

Comment: Well, your answer is good however I think that you'r solution is in sql+ and not plsql. If I copy your solution I get the return like this: {<ename=John,job=janitor>,}. So it dosen't view the result for me the same way as you get it..

Comment: Where did you run that code? In SQL Developer? If so, double click the result, then click the "pencil" button in the right hand corner of that line and you'll see the result the way you wanted it. Basically, it is not that function returned wrong result, but the fact that you don't know how to properly view it.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL Developer. You are right, now I see it as I want!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you do.